# How to create a folder (if not present) with Logger.new?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, logging

I'm trying to register a new log

```
@@my_logger ||= Logger.new("#{Rails.root}/log/my.log")
```

but when I try to generate new folders , to put it inside

```
@@my_logger ||= Logger.new("#{Rails.root}/log/#{today.to_s}/my.log")
```

it returns `Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory`

May it be a permission problem?
How to create a folder (if not present) with Logger.new?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Try something like this.

```
  dir = File.dirname("#{Rails.root}/log/#{today}/my.log")

  FileUtils.mkdir_p(dir) unless File.directory?(dir)

  @@my_logger ||= Logger.new("#{Rails.root}/log/#{today}/my.log")
```

Answer (score 18):

You can also do this way

```
directory_name = "name"
Dir.mkdir(directory_name) unless File.exists?(directory_name)
```

Answer (score 6):

Automatic creation of logging directories has been deprecated in rails. Here's a code snippet from the Logger.new code:

```
ActiveSupport::Deprecation.warn("Automatic directory creation for '#{log}' is deprecated. Please make sure the directory for your log file exists before creating the logger. ")
```

Accepted practice now is to make sure the log file (and directory) exist before creating the logger.

A way to make sure the directory exists ahead of time might be to use code similar to this:

```
log_file_name = '/path/to/my.log'
unless File.exist?(File.dirname(log_file_name))
  FileUtils.mkdir_p(File.dirname(log_file_name))
end
```

Comment: Thank you for the info.... So it was deprecated.... When I've asked, I meant to know if there was a param for Logger initializer which would handle creation of folders..